# What's the jQuery way of writing this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't like the syntax `onclick='javascript:doSomething(...`.

How could I write this in jQuery?

```
<a onclick='javascript:doSomething(\"" + 
aName + 
"\",\"" + 
bName + 
"\",\"" + 
aLink + 
"\",\"" + 
aText + 
"\",\"" + 
aUrl + 
"\"); 
return false;' 
href='#'>
    <img title='Do something' id='doSomethingIcon' src='/images/doSomething.png'>
</a>
```

Comment: What function is this calling?

Answer (score 4):

You would use event handlers/bindings in jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function () {
    doSomething(/* ... */);
    return false; // prevent default behaviour (returning false implies
                  // event.preventDefault and event.stopPropagation)
});
```

`.click(handler)` is a short way of saying `.bind('click', handler)`. Have a look at the [event docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) for further details. [The selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) should help to find the right selector for your situation.

Comment: returning false doesn't prevent the normal behavihour of the element, for that you need to use preventDefault() method

Comment: @yoda: You're wrong. `return false;` implies `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()`. Please remove your downvote.

Comment: Sorry for that @elusive. You should also explain what that implies, imo.

Comment: Handily, I was explaining the difference to a friend the other day with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/XTY5c/

Comment: @yoda: I did that. It should be clear now. @Jonathon Bolster: That is a nice one. Everyone should have a look at the event docs so that you can use what you need. I chose `return false` for simplicity here. The question was about event binding, right?

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you would use the [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method to assign a function to the `onclick` event.

```
$("#doSomething").click(function(e){
    doSomething('"'" + aName + '","' + bName + '","' + aLink + '","' + aText + '","' + aUrl + '"');

    return false;
});
```

The `$("#doSomething")` references the element with the ID of `doSomething`

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have `<a id="testID" href="#"><img...></a>`

```
$('#testID').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // This is same as return; you have.

    doSomething(\"" + 
        aName + 
        "\",\"" + 
        bName + 
        "\",\"" + 
        aLink + 
        "\",\"" + 
        aText + 
        "\",\"" + 
        aUrl + 
    "\"); 
});
```

Comment: Just so you know, `e.preventDefault()` isn't the same as `return false`. Returning false runs `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropogation`. In this case, we don't know if it matters but it is handy to know (Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/XTY5c/)